# Query performance measure Cosmos DB

Tags: c#, performance, querying, azure-cosmosdb

Im new to Cosmos DB and i try to do some performance measurements for querying against a cosmos db collection (documentdb api) duo c#-sdk. I try to do it using a simple Stopwatch. But when i query with the following code snipped, i always get fluctuating measurement data between 14ms and like 33ms. Its independent if i query a record about one or 10000 data and also independent if i query against a partitionkey-value, another indexed value or a not indexed value with EnableScaninQuery active. So i guess with this code is something wrong? I expect very much higher time to collect 10000 records of unindexed data rather than querying one partitionkey data. Also the FeedOptions provide the PopulateQueryMetrics method. Is there any way to get access to the querytime using this metrics in my c# application?

```
FeedOptions asd = new FeedOptions
        {
            EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true,
            // EnableScanInQuery = true,
            //PopulateQueryMetrics = true,
            MaxItemCount = 500,
            MaxBufferedItemCount = 10000,
            MaxDegreeOfParallelism = -1
        }; 
watch.Start();
            try
            {
                IDocumentQuery<Item> query = client.CreateDocumentQuery<Item>(
                    UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(Database, coll), asd)
                    .Where(m => m.userid == 999999).AsDocumentQuery<Item>();

                WriteToConsoleAndPromptToContinue("Query took {0} ms ", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
                watch.Stop();
```

Comment: What is the network distance between your database access client and the CosmosDb instance on Azure?

Answer (score 0):

Try iterating through the whole result set to produce reliable results.

```
while (query.HasMoreResults)  
{
    var result = await query.ExecuteNextAsync<Item>();

    // Process paged results
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer, ill do this already to print me some informations about each queried item. But in which way i can measure the time with this processing?

Comment: The code shown in your question measures elapsed time before all the database query results have been materialised in your client-side code. If you insert my suggested code block just before the WriteToConsoleAndPromptToContinue() measurment statement I reckon you will get realistic timings. You should also count the docs returned just to verify your query.

Comment: thank you. But i dont want to process the result, i only want to query some documents and measure the time for this. Doing it with your example results in querys based on the partitionkey for one element in times like 5000ms. The SLAs grants querys under 10ms without processing them. So i guess my previous results with measurements about 14-33ms could be realistic values (based on client-side latency) for only querying the values and not even processing them?

Comment: If you are seeing a 5000ms query time for querying and materialising a single mid sized (1K) object then something is wrong with your test setup. The CPU effort to instantiate a DocumentDb json query result client-side is tiny compared with the rest of the query mechanics. Have you eliminated API and connection warm-up costs by measuring the second and not the first test query?

Comment: Sorry i cant really follow you. What do you mean with eliminating API and connection warm-up cost? The only time measurement i used is this one you can see in original post